# Checkbox control for iOS application

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, checkbox, controls

Is there any checkbox control in the object library for iOS applications? The nearest thing I see is the switch control, which can take a boolean value.

Comment: UISegmentedControl may help you

Comment: No there is no default UI Control for checkbox or radio button , here u have to use 2 different images for checked and unchecked and control them logically

Comment: Use UIButton states for check/uncheck marks. Put images of uncheck(normal state) and check (selected state).

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227366/what-is-the-best-way-to-make-a-uibutton-checkbox

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use the selected state of a UIButton, set different images (or also texts) for differents (via code, or Interface Builder) :

```
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected.png"]
        forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unselected.png"]
        forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

And in the touch up inside action :

```
- (IBAction)buttonTouched:(id)sender
{
    button.selected = !button.selected;
    // add other logic
}
```

Comment: This is an open source library providing implementation for it. 
https://github.com/t4ku/RadioButtonWithUIKit

Comment: Anirudha - you could set the background image instead, this might be what you say 'does not work'. The image is the image on the button, like the label. The background image is what is commonly used to change the whole button.

Answer (score 2):

//define property of button

**Declare Unchecked Image**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [_checkboxButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

**Checked Image**.

```
- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender
{
    if (_checkboxButton.selected == YES)
    {
        [_checkboxButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        _checkboxButton.selected = NO;
    }
    else
    {
        [_checkboxButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        _checkboxButton.selected = YES;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I use for two checkboxes on the screen. (I put them at the bottom of two pictures that are also on the screen. I use the UIControlEventTouchDown to call the checkBoxTapped method. This method talks to my main view controller where I decide if the answer was correct or incorrect. Then the main view controller calls back the this view and tells it to change the blank textbox to either a check:

[image]

or an x

[image]

```
// Put the Checkboxes on the screen
UIImage *checkBox = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Checkbox"];

self.checkBoxLeft = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[self.checkBoxLeft setImage:checkBox forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.checkBoxLeft setFrame:checkBoxFrameLeft];
[self.checkBoxLeft addTarget:self 
                      action:@selector(checkBoxTapped:) 
            forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

[self.checkBoxLeft setTitle:@"checkBoxLeft" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.checkBoxLeft.contentEdgeInsets = insets;
self.checkBoxLeft.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = NO; // Keeps it from turning gray

self.checkBoxRight = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[self.checkBoxRight setImage:checkBox forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.checkBoxRight setFrame:checkBoxFrameRight];
[self.checkBoxRight addTarget:self 
                       action:@selector(checkBoxTapped:) 
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

[self.checkBoxRight setTitle:@"checkBoxRight" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.checkBoxRight.contentEdgeInsets = insets;
self.checkBoxRight.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = NO; // Keeps it from turning gray

- (void)checkBoxTapped:(UIButton *)buttonPressed {
    [[self delegate] checkBoxTapped:buttonPressed.currentTitle];
}

- (void)highlightCheckbox:(NSString *)checkboxToHighlight withHighlight:(NSString *)highlight {

    if ( [checkboxToHighlight isEqualToString:@"left"] ){
        [self.checkBoxLeft setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:highlight] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        [self.checkBoxRight setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:highlight] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```