# Sticky buttons on iPhone program

Tags: ios, xcode, button, sticky

Hullo,
I have an app view rather crowded to insert the necessary switches in order to toggle 6 values associated to icons. So I would have appreciated if it were possible to make them sticky buttons, namely to have them independently keep the pressure when clicked in order for me to read the ones in that state when exiting the view.
I read there exists such a technique for Mac but that does not translate to iOS. Hw could I do that?

Thanks, Fabrizio

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for a checkbox functionality. Have the button change images when it's pressed, then use that to determine its state.

I'm on my phone so this took a bit, but here's a link to how to make a checkbox in objective-c [What is the best way to make a UIButton checkbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227366/what-is-the-best-way-to-make-a-uibutton-checkbox)

Note that you don't need to use normal checkbox images.